# Xamarin Form Stacklayout not resetting/Cached

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

We have a class that is consist of property say 'ItemJson' as JSON text, which is later convert to `List<Class2>` in read only property  called 'Items'.. now we use that Items to bind a Stacklayout in UI. On button action we save the ItemJson to database through API and move user to thanks screen.
When user came back he is suppose to see blank screen and for that we have Viewmodel set to reinitialize our object using new keyword. But it doesn't clear the Stacklayout or the Items variable although ItemJson is blank out. This results in old Items are still visible to user.

So my class is (Example)

```
Myclass { 
 public string ItemJson {get; set;} 
 public List<Class2> Items { get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(ItemJson); } }
}
```

And my UI use Items as

```
<Stacklayout Bindable="{Binding Obj.Items}" ... >
...DataTemplate etc..</Stacklayout>
```

My ViewModel has function called onAppearing of UI, that did

```
Obj = new MyClass();
```

But it doesn't clear the Items property.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, We navigate through `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` and I even try to use `Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync()` in hope that it don't reuse last UI screen and hence come blank. But it didn't work. We cannot recreate full screen through variable as in our process we have to switch to various screen in between and come back. so If recreate or rePush new object it effect the flow of application. So we need just to clear in when we press save button. And on Save button I try to reinitialize this object but it is getting cached by some internal programming.

Comment: `OnAppearing()` is called multiple times during the app lifecycle - each time the page is about to become visible. Do not confuse it with the constructor. Please provide more details of your code, e.g. how and where else do you use `Obj`? Please provide actual code and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because your code currently will not compile as it's not valid XAML.

Comment: *"My ViewModel has function called onAppearing of UI"* - **Does that method get called when you expect it to?** I doubt it; put a breakpoint in it. Also, show more code, including the method declararions. E.g. `public void OnAppearing(){ Obj = new MyClass(); }`. Show how those methods get called. Anything you say in natural language, make sure someone could mentally run the program using the code you show, even if you didn't also have the natural language description. (Its good to have the descriptions; just make sure the code is also complete.)

Comment: @Julian I cannot make minmal reporuciable code and it is code for client and is very big project cannot share original code. I am not allow to share that even here.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve in my ViewlModel I have various variable that I initialize using string.Empty or new <Class> name as required and Obj is one of those variable, and In myClass's constructor,  I ensure that ItemJson get set to string.Empty and throw INotifier for Items as well . But they are not getting set. And yes they are called I can see `Items` not getting reset after `Obj = new  MyClass()` call.

Comment: @SumitGupta Of course you can provide a minimal reproducible example for this. You don't have to use the actual production code from the project, just create an example from scratch that shows the same behavior. One of the issues with your question is that the code example is neither valid nor very useful.

Comment: Like Julian says. Can't help you from the information given so far. Start over with a new project template. Add just enough code to cause the problem. Put that code in the question. Ideally, make a public github repo people can run.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't share sufficient information (yet) about your code and the exact problem with it, I'll try to give a more generic answer based on how I understood your problem.

## Make properties observable

Your class needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface in order to notify the UI about changes to the `Items` when the `ItemJson` changes:

```cs
public class Myclass : INotifyPropertyChanged { 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }   

    private string _itemJson;
    public string ItemJson
    {
        get => _itemJson;
        set
        {
            if(_itemJson == value) return;
            _itemJson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        }
    }

    public List<Class2> Items { get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(ItemJson); } }
}
```

If the `Items` object is supposed to be empty, you need to set the `ItemJson` to an empty JSON array, e.g.:

```cs
Obj.ItemJson = "[]";
```

This will clear the list, because `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));` is called by the property setter, which then notifies the UI to update the binding to `Items`.

## Some notes and suggestions for improvement

This is not an ideal implementation, but that's because the setup of your Page and ViewModel doesn't seem to be well-designed (again, basing this on little actual information).

You shouldn't deserialize the JSON inside of a property getter - what if an exception is thrown by the parser? It's also not a good design to have a dependency on a JSON structure, because you shouldn't need to have an empty array or list in order to update the `Items` property to become empty.

Rather, you should directly set the `Items` property, which should also be observable:

```cs
private List<Class2> _items;
public List<Class2> Items
{
    get => _items;
    set
    {
        if(_items == value) return;
        _items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Then you can set the list directly after deserializing the JSON, e.g.:

```cs
public void UpdateData(string json)
{
    try
    {
        List<Class2> newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(json);
        Items = newData;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Items = new List<Class2>();
    }
}

public void ClearData()
{
    Items = new List<Class2>();
}
```

Comment: I do have properties as INotifyPropertyChanged, my Class has all Properties as InotifyPropertyChanged. The ItemJson getter also throw Notification change for Items.

Comment: On Second point I fetch ItemJson From Database and put it here, and when I have to bind the object to UI then I have to use Items property hence I have Getter of it only. My assumption is that when Binding start it fetch data from ItemsJson, Deserialize it and make list. I have try catch block and if error come it throw new Empty List. I feel that is more efficient to deseriliae it at time of binding then when loading data in object of ItemJson as it use memory to store it if not needed.

Comment: @SumitGupta If your class implements INotifyPropertyChanged then why don't you show that in your question? Getters don't need to invoke any PropertyChanged event, that is not useful at all. Only setters need to invoke that event to inform subscribers that a property value has changed so that they can fetch it again. It's pretty useless calling OnPropertyChanged() in the getter. Have you tried to apply my suggestions?

Comment: Oh I mistype throw in getter, it is setter for ItemJson .. let me see if my boss allow me to create sample for you.